# iPhone Or Mac Header File?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, file, header

Just a small question...

How is it that you tell the difference between an iPhone header file which you can use in conjunction with iPhone development, or a mac specific header file.

Many thanks,

Stu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many are the same, but not all are included in both. It all depends on which SDK you are building against as to which you have available to you. Please see the [iPhone Reference Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html) and the [Mac OS X Reference Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/navigation/).

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

One quick way is to try and pull up something the header references in the XCode documentation, if you check the document sets the docs are looking at and un-check "MacOS" leaving the iPhone stuff, it will not find anything the iPhone cannot use.